# log4j xml configuration error

Tags: java, xml, configuration, log4j

Every time I compile with maven I get the following exception.

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /logs/jump_page.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:295)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseRoot(DOMConfigurator.java:492)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:1006)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:872)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:778)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:289)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1116)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:914)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:604)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:310)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<clinit>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:24)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.<init>(JUnit4TestSet.java:45)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.createTestSet(JUnit4DirectoryTestSuite.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.locateTestSets(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.createSuiteFromDefinition(Surefire.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:338)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:997)
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [FILE].
```

I have this configuration in my log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- TOMCAT SERVER FILE -->
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
    debug="false">

    <!-- ============================== -->
    <!-- APPENDERS                      -->
    <!-- ============================== -->

    <appender name="FILE"
        class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/jump_page.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%d %-5p [%c{1}] [%t] [%x] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- ================================ -->
    <!-- CATEGORIES - APPLICATION LOGGING -->
    <!-- ================================ -->

    <!-- Limit the org.apache.commons category to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose -->
    <category name="net">
        <priority value="WARN" />
    </category>

    <category name="org.apache.commons">
        <priority value="WARN" />
    </category>

    <category name="org.springframework">
        <priority value="WARN" />
    </category>

    <!-- Setup the Travelocity categories -->
    <category name="com.travelocity">
        <priority value="INFO" />
    </category>





    <!-- ============================== -->
    <!-- ROOT CATEGORY                  -->
    <!-- ============================== -->
    <root>
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

After searching a lot I always find the same answer about permissions, but it is no use in this situation.

It works when I use the absolute path.

Plase, help!

Thanks!

EDIT:

I'm using tomcat 6.0

```
-bash-3.00$ /opt/tomcat/instances/tomcat-8080/bin/startupDev.sh version
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat/instances/tomcat-8080
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/instances/tomcat-8080/temp
Using JRE_HOME:       /usr/java
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${catalina.base}` is resolving to an empty string. Try using another environment variable or absolute path here:

```
<param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/jump_page.log" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try out the following to diagnose this issue further and report it back in your question. Telling us on which platform you are would help also.

### Enable debug output

In your `catalina.properties` file (located in the `conf` folder of your Tomcat installation, or `/etc/tomcat?` for Linux), please append this property to enable log4j debugging output.

```
log4j.debug=true
```

This should give you more hints on what's going wrong.

### Test the file path with static and complete path configuration

Also, while the `catalina.base` system property should be set in a Tomcat's environment, is this possible that log4j actually tries to access the `/logs` folder from the filesystem root? As in, the `catalina.base` system property would not be set or considered? What happens if you put a complete and static path in your configuration?